# Force to throw exception on VS

Tags: c#, mysql, exception, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-community

I'm getting thise messages on VS output window:

> Exception thrown: 'MySql.Data.Types.MySqlConversionException' in
> MySql.Data.dll Exception thrown:
>
> 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in mscorlib.dll
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in
> mscorlib.dll

How do I force VS to throw those exception when they happen rather run in "silent mode"? I did look up for `MySql.Data.Types.MySqlConversionException` on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> for know about .NET native exceptions, I guess.

I'm running already in debug mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the "Exception Settings" Window (Debug/Windows/Exception Settings) you can control on which exceptions Visual Studio breaks into the code.